# Kotlin: Specify input-constraints in interface

Tags: validation, kotlin, exception, interface, defensive-programming

Lets say I have the following interface:

```
interface MathThing {

    fun mathFunction(x : Int)
}
```

Let's say the constraint I want to put onto this function is that x cannot be negative.

How can I make sure that every time this (or any other arbitrary) condition isn't met on a object of type MathThing, a (custom) exception is thrown?

Comment: Maybe use the unsigned integer instead. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#unsigned-integers

Comment: This is just an easy example that I don't actually need. I want to know how any constraint can be enforced. But I will look up this class regardless.

Comment: In general interfaces can't enforce anything in their implementations. You add a comment saying that implementations should check that something is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a wrapper class for your function parameters. You can make an extension function so it's a little easier to pass values to the function.

```
data class NonNegative(val value: Int) {
    init{ if (value < 0) throw IllegalArgumentException("Input must not be negative.") }
}

fun Int.nonNegative() = NonNegative(this)

interface MathThing {
    fun mathFunction(x : NonNegative)
}
```